# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. Failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am working on my academic project College Management system android app. I tried runing this GitHub project [GPM app](https://github.com/prashantchanne12/GPM-Government-Polytechnic-Mumbai-App.git). Came across many errors but this one I couldn't able to solve

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\sivan\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\806b9598bdc7c05f40251eaf9ba49c1f\jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.1\AndroidManifest.xml:30:9-32:61: AAPT: error: unexpected element <property> found in <manifest><application>.
```

###### AndroidManifest.xml:30:9-32:61

```
<property
            android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG"
            android:resource="@xml/ga_ad_services_config" />
```

Please help me to solve this error

I tried changing **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** from 27 to 28

Comment: Your link does not show the project, it just links to stackoverflow

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, any updates?

Comment: I fixed it by downgrading firebase versions.